# Глагольные категории

Tags: морфология, глаголы

Глаголы обладают различными морфологическими категориями и признаками.

Найдите "лишний" в данном ряду глагол.

1)плыть

2)вести

3)тащить

4)брести

5)летать

Comment: Один из глаголов является итеративным  (от лат. iterare вторично делать, повторять).

Comment: Спасибо)) Итеративные - вторично делать, повторять) то же, что моторно-кратные глаголы (См. глаголы движения). Бегать, ездить, ползать и т. д. Какой из всех

Comment: Летать, наверное. Пара лететь - летать

Comment: Так здесь итеративные. Выберите тот, которое обозначает на  неоднонаправленное  движение.

Comment: Все я поняла. Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Глагол "летать" - лишний в данном ряду.